# Is there a Visual Interface Designer plugin for Play Framework?

Tags: playframework

Similar to that of GWT or Visual Studio. Something like drag and drop with Ajax support and dynamically generated web pages. Should support css, javascript (jquery or prototype) and html design

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing like that for Play Framework.

But nothing stops you from use dreamweaver or any other crap to generate (ugly) html/js code. 
Don't hope it will be even near to acceptable quality code. As every Designer tools, generated code will never be as clear, as optimized as manually written code by a developper.